# Sudo NOPASSWD not registering/working/showing

Tags: bash, sudo, rhel

Sudo version: 1.7.2p1

I have the following (sanitised) lines in my sudoers file (at the end of the file):

```
Runas_Alias GROUPALIASNAME = user1,user2, user3
Cmnd_Alias APP = /path/to/binary/setup -f *, /path/to/binary/patchbinary
%groupname
ALL=(root)NOPASSWD:SOFTWARE,(GROUPALIASNAME)NOPASSWD:APP
```

If I run "sudo -ll" as a user from %groupname (user3) I get the following:

```
Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: root
    Commands:
        NOPASSWD: /bin/rpm, /usr/bin/up2date, /usr/bin/yum

    RunAsUsers: user1, user2, user3
    Commands:
        /path/to/binary/setup -f *,
        /path/to/binary/patchbinary
```

I can't seem to get the second "nopasswd" entry to work. I've tried removing all whitespace, adding whitespace. I've tried "NoPasswd:all" which just makes it give "all" rather than "nopasswd:all". I know the rule is matching because clearly I can see the very specific entries expanding. The entry being at the end should rule out any conflicting rules. 
Any ideas or suggestions on diagnosing this? Unfortunately its a 'secure' machine so applying patches/updating sudo isn't an option.
**The reference to "SOFTWARE" is just a default sudoers entry.

EDIT: For now I have worked around the issue by splitting the 1 line into 2 lines. I made no other modifications than to insert a line break with %groupname ALL= and it now correctly shows the right to execute the command with no password. However it still requires a password.

Comment: Could you post your complete (redacted) sudoers, because the defaults can vary between operating environments (i.e. Debian vs OpenSuse vs ... )?

Comment: Also, when posting code / output, please try and avoid posting from HTML as it doesn't render properly - it needs to be indented with four spaces; as a tip, if you copied from an email paste into a text editor and fix it there before pasting into SO :-)

Comment: Thanks for formatting it. I wasn't sure how to achieve the right effect. Posting the whole sudoers is hard because there'd be so much that I would need to change, and in changing it I might introduce mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To aide debugging and maintainability you should split your rules:

```
%groupname ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: SOFTWARE
%groupname ALL=(GROUPALIASNAME) NOPASSWD: APP
```

Splitting your rules onto different lines makes it clearer what you are trying to do.

Ensure that the user you are trying to run sudo as, is in `%groupname`.

Ensure that you are using something like `sudo -u user1` (etc) so the Runas_alias is actually effected.

The other thing you need to do, is if you are testing changes as the destination user, if you just added your user to `%groupname`, you need to log out and log back in for the group add to actually work.

Comment: I did split it and I think the problem is actually 2 problems. The first is as detailed in original post (the NOPASSWD not registering against that Cmnd_Alias) the second is probably just a lack of knowledge on my part.
If I run 'sudo -u user1 APP' it'll execute properly. If I run 'sudo -Hinu user1 APP' then I get the password error. I normally don't use Hinu so I'll look more closely into how the other parameters affect the result.
Edit: to clarify- once I split the lines the NOPASSWD shows up in sudo -ll. Im not sure if I can leave it split in prod- the sudoers file is huge already.

Comment: Its the "i" in -Hinu that causes the break. Probably something in the target service account's profile or something. -Hnu works fine. Unfortunately I have to strictly use -Hinu so back to the books. Will leave unanswered for now in case your next response is even better.

Comment: As identified in edits above, there were 2 issues.

The first is that the single line (for the %group) needed to be split into 2. I'm not clear on why that is.
The second issue was the "-i" flag on sudo not listed in my original question. The "-i" translates to "bash -c" when executing.

So the end result is that APP gets defined as it was before, but with "/bin/bash -c" appended before each command, and the line beginning with %groupname is split per Andrew McDonnell's post. I have other lines for other users and groups that are all single line without an issue. Not sure why but ok to close.

Comment: Another issue is that one of the users requires korn shell, which then breaks the bash -c explicit line. editing /etc/passwd entry for that user is the work around.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the issue in your case specifically, but I came across this question when trying to troubleshoot my own issue.

In my case, I had created a new file in the `sudoers.d` directory.  Specifically, it was named `100-backupreader-privileged-scripts.conf`.  Nothing seemed to be working, and I spent quite a bit of time searching and trying all sorts of various syntax, to no avail.

Then I read this line in the manpage (`man 5 sudoers`)

> The #includedir directive can be used to create a sudoers.d directory that the system package manager can drop sudoers file rules into as part of package installation.  For example, given:
>
> #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
>
> sudo will suspend processing of the current file and read each file in /etc/sudoers.d, skipping file names that end in ‘~’ **or contain a ‘.’ character** to avoid causing problems with package manager or editor temporary/backup files.

Turns out you can't name a file `something.conf` in the sudoers.d folder.  I renamed the file to remove the period and everything started working!